# Get email addresses of users through powershell into CSV file

Tags: powershell, automation, email-address, get-aduser

I have a PowerShell script (big thanks to Santiago Squarzon) that pulls off users who have been inactive for past 6 months.

Currently work fine and outputs:

```
1. Username 
2. Name
3. DistinguishedName
4. LastLogon
```

This is part of the code:

```
$logons.Values | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name              = $_.Name
        SamAccountName    = $_.SamAccountName
        DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName
        lastLogon         = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($_.lastLogon).ToString('u')
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\InactiveUsers.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am also trying to pull off users email address. I have tried to add the following code but the EmailAddress field is blank in my CSV:

```
EmailAddress      = $user.EmailAddress
```

```
EmailAddress      = $_.EmailAddress
```

```
EmailAddress      = $_.mail
```

```
EmailAddress      = $user.mail
```

None of the above work.

Comment: You left out the part that gets the users from AD.. You need to ask for the email addres in the properties parameter: `Properties = 'lastLogon', 'EmailAddress'`. Then `EmailAddress  = $_.EmailAddress` should work

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but `Properties = 'lastLogon', 'EmailAddress'` where doe this exactly need to go in my script. Is this at the start before $logon?

Comment: Right, you just need to change `Properties = 'lastLogon'` to `Properties = 'lastLogon', 'mail’` in the code from the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I know see it I was looking in the wrong place (still learning) email addresses are now being pulled off. How do I accept your answer on this? I guess this is sneaky to ask of you Santiago but I have another question (which is posted) "Specifying a list of usernames to be deleted from AD via powershell" I can do this via .txt file with username only but not CSV file get errors.